# python short circuit or bug when if condition

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how python short-circuit works

```
text = 'test'
print(0 or 1 if text else 2)
# outputs 1 which is expected
print(3 or 1 if text else 2)
#outputs 3 which is expected
text = ''
print(2 or 1 if text else 5)
# outputs 5 which is not expected
```

Can someone explain `2 or 1 if '' else 5` gives 5 instead of 2, I have checked [Boolean Operations — and, or, not](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) but didn't understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: check ``bool(text) -> False``

Comment: you need to understand `if foo else bar` first.

Comment: `print(2 or 1 if text else 5)` becomes `if text: print(2 or 1); else print(5)`

Comment: If what you expected was 2, then you should've written `print(2 or (1 if text else 5))`

Comment: @sushanth in the docs it says "This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is false." `2 or 1` should always be 2 and the second argument not evaluated

Comment: in your case `text` starts as `test` which is `bool(text) -> True` since `bool` on text returns `True` on not empty. Then you're changing `text` to `''` which is `False`.

Comment: `in the docs it says [...]` If that's your question, then the answer is to wrap it with parenthesis as in my 3rd comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is the parenthesis on your conditions, the best way to understand `if foo else bar`, python evaluates checks the condition `if` then based on it evaluates foo or bar

```
def foo():
    print('hello world')
    # returns None -> bool(None) is False
def fun():
    return "Test"

print(foo() or foo() or foo() if 1 else 2)
#in this case `if 1` is `True` so it will run all 3 or conditions and print hello world three times then None.
print(foo() or fun() or foo() or foo() if 1 else 2)
# in this case `if 1` True but will print hello world only once then Test
```

in the case of `2 or 1 if '' else 5`, python reads it as `(2 or 1) if '' else 5` which is obviously gives 5

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand `if foo else bar` first.

`print(2 or 1 if text else 5)` becomes

```
if text:
  print(2 or 1);
else:
  print(5)
```

If what you expected was 2, then you should've written

```
print(2 or (1 if text else 5))
```

which becomes

```
if text:
  print(2 or 1)
else:
  print(2 or 5)
```

which prints `2` in both cases

in your case `text` starts as `test` which is `bool(text) -> True` since `bool` on text returns `True` on not empty. Then you're changing `text` to `''` which is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

When `text` has a string value other than `''`, bool(text) returns True.
On the other hand, when `text` has the value `''`, bool(text) returns False.
Because bool(text) returns False, 5 is printed.

Comment: I understand that completely, but the first condition of the or in my case is already True. why would it bother with `1 if text else 5`